# C# How to make Stack function like List?

Tags: c#, list, xna, stack

As part of the requirements, I'm trying to modify my code so that it can behave the same way as my original code however I can't seem to figure it out.

I've already done some modification and it compiles fine however I can't get the stack class to function like the list:

List (original):

```
private List<Gem> gems = new List<Gem>();
private List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();

private void UpdateGems(GameTime gameTime)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; ++i)
    {
        Gem gem = gems[i];
        gem.Update(gameTime);

        if (gem.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
        {
            gems.RemoveAt(i--);
            OnGemCollected(gem, Player);
        }
    }
}
```

Stack (my modified version):

```
private Stack<Gem> gems = new Stack<Gem>();
private Stack<Enemy> enemies = new Stack<Enemy>();

/// <summary>
/// Animates each gem and checks to allows the player to collect them.
/// </summary>
private void UpdateGems(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Gem[] array = gems.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < gems.Count; ++i)
    {
        Gem gem = array[i];
        gem.Update(gameTime);
        if (gem.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
        {
            gems.Pop();
            OnGemCollected(gem, Player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling a stack won't work this way. Seems as though you are removing items from part way throughout the collection as the `Player` intersects the `gem`. With a `Stack` you can _only_ remove from the end of the collection (`Pop`), so I don't know what your intent is to switch to a `Stack`.

Comment: What behaviour exactly are you looking for? `Stack.Pop()` removes the last added element, whereas you in the first code sample remove them if `gem.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle)` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Also, I think your title is backwards. Shouldn't it read "how to make Stack function like List"? It's relatively easy to make a `List` function like a `Stack` (if not inefficiently), but impossible to make a `Stack` behave like a `List`. (they are fundamentally two different things which behave two different ways for two usually different reasons)

Comment: I'm trying to make the stack code sample function like the first list sample. That is, in the second code sample I want the elements to be removed if 'gem.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle)' evaluates to true.

Comment: @Katie You cannot really use a `Stack` for this. What is wrong with using a `List`?

Comment: Nothings wrong with a list, however I'm required to use stack for this purpose.

Comment: Isn't a stack usually based on a list?

Comment: @Katie If you want to use a stack no matter the cost, you can work with two stacks: un-pop all the gems from the first one, and put in the second one only the gems that doesn't intersect with the player. But I don't really see the point.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide an example?

Comment: You're missing a `i--`.

Comment: @antonijn Where abouts?

Comment: @sircodesalot: if your question wasn't rhetorical, yes. It's an unordered list with restricted insert and remove (push(), pop()). FILO - I guess I should say *could* be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of:

```
private Stack<Gem> gems = new Stack<Gem>();
private Stack<Enemy> enemies = new Stack<Enemy>();

/// <summary>
/// Animates each gem and checks to allows the player to collect them.
/// </summary>
private void UpdateGems(GameTime gameTime)
{
    var newGems = new Stack<Gem>(this.gems.Count);

    while (this.gems.Count > 0)    
    {
        var gem = this.gems.Pop();
        gem.Update(gameTime);

        if (gem.BoundingCircle.Intersects(Player.BoundingRectangle))
        {
            OnGemCollected(gem, Player);
        }
        else
        {
            newGems.Push(gem);
        }
    }

    this.gems = newGems;
}
```

Doesn't make much sense though.